How can I make format constexpr?
I have the following function:
constexpr int count_format_placeholders(const std::string_view format)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < format.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(format[i] == '{' && format[i + 1] == '}')
        {
            ++count;
            ++i;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

I have defined two functions, func and func2:
template<typename... Args>
constexpr int func(std::string_view format)
{
    return count_format_placeholders(format);
}

template<typename... Args>
constexpr int func2(std::string_view format)
{
    constexpr int i = count_format_placeholders(format);
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr std::string_view format{"{} {} {} {}:{}:{}"};

    constexpr int num_placeholders = count_format_placeholders(format);       //compiles
    std::cout << num_placeholders << std::endl;
    constexpr int num_placeholders2 = func<int, int>(format);                 //compiles
    std::cout << num_placeholders2 << std::endl;
    constexpr int num_placeholders3 = func2<int, int>(format);               //doesn't compile, why?
    std::cout << num_placeholders3 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

The direct call to count_format_placeholders, and func work fine. Calling func2, however, generates a format is not constant expression error.
Why is this, and how can I fix this?
Easy testing: https://godbolt.org/z/9zoWM95hh

@user12002570 but why is gcc accepting the usage of func but not of func2 ? Is there UB somewhere ?

@user12002570 Clang is actually fine with it if I comment out the function as well as the call. I guess its compiling unused functions too.

@user12002570 Do you know why this is by chance? It is rather annoying as I would like to use the statement present in function two. But it doesn't seem to be acceptable.

Why isn't this std::string_view a constant expression?

@user12002570 According to that answer it, function parameters cannot be constexpr. If so, I wonder why func works fine? RVO and move semantics cannot be the issue since this is compile time (but I tested disabling them anyway and they are not).

Yup, seems strange since function parameters aren't constexpr. Also as you said, since this is at compile time elision cannot be the issue.

@wohlstad Here if were to be any UB, it must be detected as this is happening at compile time.

@user12002570 I used "UB" inadvertently. But my question remains if you know why gcc treats func and func2 differently ?

@wohlstad Not only gcc but both clang and msvc also treat func and func2 differently. The call to func2 in OP's example compiles in all but not the call to func2. I don't know the reason for the difference though. First I was thinking it maybe related to some optimization/elision but since this is at compile time, I don't think that should work .

Try removing constexpr from constexpr int i = count_format_placeholders(format); and your program should compile

I can confirm this does not have to do with function inlining either. I used __declspec(noinline) in msvc and __attribute__ ((noinline)) in gcc and clang.

@user12002570 Interseting. I wonder if it is an anomaly in the compilers or some corner  case in the stadard that dictates this different treatment.

@LluísAlemany-Puig It does, but the issue is I need it to be known at compile time. Additionally, it does not explain why it works in certain cases and not in others.

True, I did not explain why it compiles in one case and not in others. But removing the constexpr qualifier from the definition of i in func2 makes the result known at compile time. Try adding static_assert( func2<int,int>("{}") == 1 ); after removing the constexpr qualifier. It should work at least in C++20 and gcc trunk. https://godbolt.org/z/j9f8h98o7

@Eshy the call to func works fine because the call to func as a whole is a constant expression. Not everything in a constexpr function needs to be a constant expression in itself. func2 is creating a constant expression in its body (within another constant expression), and different rules apply to that other constant expression inside of it. You're getting constant expressions and constant evaluations sort of mixed up here. Just because something is constant-evaluated (i.e. "done at compile-time") doesn't mean that there are multiple constant expressions, or that there need to be.

@LluísAlemany-Puig interesting! The assert seems to pass just fine!

@JanSchultke "the call to func works fine because the call to func as a whole is a constant expression" To clarify, does this mean the function has nothing but constexprs, or is it because returning a constexpr from a constexpr function is equivalent to just having a constexpr?

Nothing inside of func is a constant expression, but func<int, int>(format) is constant-evaluated because it appears as the initializer of a constexpr variable. So the call is constant-evaluated and everything in func during the evaluation is known at compile-time, but nothing is constant-evaluated in a separate constant expression, just the call to func.

@JanSchultke But, since parameters cannot be guaranteed to be constexpr, how does func  know format is okay to use here?

You don't need format to be a constant expression to work with it at compile time. count_format_placeholders is given a std::string_view, and if func is currently constant-evaluated, that format must be an object created during that constant evaluation. So func just has a std::string_view and can work with that with no issue. You only need things to be constant expressions when you want to use them say, as the size of an array, as a template argument, etc. It's not necessary 99% of the time.

It's okay for the same reason you can write int x = 0; int y = x; in a constexpr function. x isn't a constant expression, but you can still constant-evaluate that code.

@JanSchultke Interesting, it seems I have misunderstood constexprs. If I understand correctly, constexpr does not translate to "known at compile time". A variable (for example) can be known at compile time without necessary being a constexpr? I had previously assumed this was only the case with compiler optimizations and constexpr was a way to ensure this.

What actually makes things happen at compile time is constant evaluation, such as when things are manifestly constant-evaluated. constexpr on a variable means that initializer has to be a constant expression and results in constant-evaluation of that initializer. Of course, things can happen "at compile-time" as the result of compiler optimizations, independent of constant evaluation.

@JanSchultke So is a constexpr simply a special cpp tool to ensure values are specifically inputted as a literal by the user (or I suppose are template parameters)?

For variables, yeah, kinda.
